# Undefined index when trying to draw a value from database

Tags: php

trying to code a control panel for registered users on my website but im stuck. alright well I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I have a login system where I am using sessions. I used the session code to draw specific values pertaining to the character that's logged on. I can get the username to display but not the other fields that im trying to draw from the database. the code I have is as fallows.

```
<?php 
 require("common.php"); 
      if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 

        header("Location: login.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 


?> 

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>  
<center> 
<table border>
<tr>
<td width="120" height="10"><center>Character</center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center>Attack</center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center>Defence</center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center>Strength</center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center>Hit points</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="120" height="10"><center><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username']); ?></center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['attack'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['defence'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['strength'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>></center></td>
<td width="120" height="10"><center><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['hits'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></center></td>
</tr>


</table></center>
```

Comment: Let's see the part of the code where `$_SESSION['user']` is defined, or show the results of `var_dump( $_SESSION );`

Comment: Have you initialized the session with `session_start()` ?

Comment: If the username displays, the session is started and data available...

Comment: yes session is open I can retrieve registered email and username just not the other 4 variables im trying to retrieve. im new to this so please explain

Comment: It's not very safe storing usernames in sessions. Plus, you need to "define" your variables, thus the `undefined` error.

Comment: I'm sure it's started in common.php and defined elsewhere during login routines. The `undefined` error is actually because one of the indexes he's trying to use doesn't exist. Not the variable as a whole. `attack, defence, strength, hits` one or more in `$_SESSION['user']` array have not been defined.

Comment: no point in putting another session_star(); I already have it defined in my redirect so when placing it on the page you get the session has already started eror

Comment: please explain how I go about creating these indexes

Comment: Somewhere you've already created one for username. Wherever that code is, we need to add for the attack, defence, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remember you always have to put

```
session_start();
```